# Meteor login error cause unmounted component

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I know this has been asked before, but I'm not understanding what's causing the problem. In this case when a user submits the login request `handleSubmit` is called and the page runs `Meteor.loginWithPassword`. The problem occours when there is a server error, ie. the users password is incorrect. `this.setState({ loginError: true })` returns a console error:

`Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the LoginPage component.`

I realise it's something to do with the component unmounting when the form is submitted but I don't understand how I suppose to fix it.

```
export default class LoginPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      email: '',
      errors: {},
      password: '',
      loginError: false
    };

    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleInputChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password, (error, result) => {
      if (error) {
        this.setState({ loginError: true });
      } else {
        console.log("success");
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form noValidate>

          {this.state.loginError
            ?
              <div className="alert alert-danger text-center" role="alert">
                Incorrect username or password.
              </div>
            : null
          }

          <SingleInput
            name={'email'}
            inputType={'email'}
            controlFunc={this.handleInputChange}
            content={this.state.email}
            placeholder={'Email'}
            bsSize={null}
            error={this.state.errors && this.state.errors.email}
          />

          <SingleInput
            name={'password'}
            inputType={'password'}
            controlFunc={this.handleInputChange}
            content={this.state.password}
            placeholder={'Password'}
            bsSize={null}
            error={this.state.errors && this.state.errors.password}
          />

          <button className="btn btn-success btn-block" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Login</button>

        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the component called LoginPage

Comment: @CagriYardimci See update

Comment: Can you confirm which setState is generating the error

Comment: this.setState({ loginError: true })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is likely in the parent component that calls `LoginPage`

```
<App>
  <HOCWrapper component={LoginPage} {...this.props} />
</App>
```

When you're calling `this.setState()`, it's not updating the Higher Order Component (AsyncWrapper), so it doesn't know to re-render to component.

So, it's passing the state to the HOC, not to LoginPage

```
const HOCWrapper = LoginPage => {
    constructor() {
      super()
      this.state = {
        loginError: true
      }
    }
```

So you need to update the HOC's state, and pass it back to the props with something like:

```
const HOCUpdater = Login => {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      loginError: []
    }
  }

  return class HOCUpdater extends Component {
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
      this.setState(nextProps);
    }
    render(){
      return createElement(LoginPage,{...this.state});
    } 
  }
}
```